# i give wrong result in 2d arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix, 2d, calculation

hi i am making a determinant calculator in c-sharp windows form but i have problem with sum result .
 the Algorithm is :
 sum  = (row11((row22 * row33) - (row23 * row32))) - (row12 ((row21 * row33) - (row23 - row31))) + (row13((row21 * row32) - (row22 - row31)));

for example this is a matrix : |1,2,3|
                               |2,3,4|
                               |5,6,7|
the result should be 0 but in my code i give 25

```
public void cal()
    {
        int[,] a = new int[3, 3];

        int row11;
        int row12;
        int row13;

        int row21;
        int row22;
        int row23;

        int row31;
        int row32;
        int row33;

        row11 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        row12 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        row13 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);

        row21 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
        row22 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text);
        row23 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text);

        row31 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox7.Text);
        row32 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox8.Text);
        row33 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox9.Text);


        a[0, 0] = row11;
        a[0, 1] = row12;
        a[0, 2] = row13;

        a[1, 0] = row21;
        a[1, 1] = row22;
        a[1, 2] = row23;

        a[2, 0] = row31;
        a[2, 1] = row32;
        a[2, 2] = row33;

        int sum = (row11 * ((row22 * row33) - (row23 * row32))) - (row12 * ((row21 * row33) - (row23 - row31))) + (row13 * ((row21 * row32) - (row22 - row31)));

        textBox19.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Comment: Break it down to smaller expressions, debug and see where exactly the problem is

Comment: i think the problem is in this line :        int sum = (row11 * ((row22 * row33) - (row23 * row32))) - (row12 * ((row21 * row33) - (row23 - row31))) + (row13 * ((row21 * row32) - (row22 - row31)));

Comment: row12 is row 1 column 2 or row 2 column 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by decomposing the determinant calcul i have 0 with your sample:

```
        var determinant = a[0, 0] * (a[1, 1] * a[2, 2] - a[2, 1] * a[1, 2]) -
                          a[0, 1] * (a[1, 0] * a[2, 2] - a[2, 0] * a[1, 2]) +
                          a[0, 2] * (a[1, 0] * a[2, 1] - a[2, 0] * a[1, 1]);
```

Comment: oh thank you .so we can't write all of this to 1 line right?

Comment: i have modified my answer to have 1 line of code, but thats is not important, dont forget the lisibility of program...